# What is the difference between Request.Body and Request.Content in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, file-upload

In ASP.NET Core Web API I have `Request.Body`

```
var rawRequestBody = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In ASP.NET MVC I have `Request.Content`

```
Stream stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I am trying to upload the file as a stream. Please suggest how I can get the file as stream with `Request.Body` in asp.net core web api controller.

I am testing the upload file using postman.

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

In *http* a body of request can have headers, some times called *content* or *payload headers*. These describe certain attributes of the body.

In regards to C#

`Body` is a [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-5.0), and is just a chunk of data representing the body of the request.

> **Stream**
>
> Provides a generic view of a sequence of bytes

`Content` is a [`HttpContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-5.0). `Content` can have extra information like *headers* to describe the Body.

> **HttpContent**
>
> A base class representing an HTTP entity **body** and **content** headers

You can read the *data* (of the *body*) from the `Content` as a `Stream` (as you have shown).

---

You can read more about headers here

[HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

> HTTP headers let the client and the server pass additional information
> with an HTTP request or response. An HTTP header consists of its
> case-insensitive name followed by a colon (:), then by its value.
> Whitespace before the value is ignored.